# Add time format (via js (jquery)) to <title> tag of html document

Tags: jquery, html

Neep help on this one:

Add time format (via js (jquery))  to  tag of html document?

If you need me to elobrate let me know, but I think it's fairly self-explanatory.

Time format from jquery which means not from server (php, etc.) but from 'user's machine'

Comment: i.e. the current date/time you mean?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp the link is pretty self explanatory, if you need me to elaborate, let me know....

Comment: Has nothing on adding to title tag though.

Comment: `var d = new Date(); $("#idOfTag").html(d);`

Comment: @A.O.: surely `document.title = new Date();`? There's little to no reason to use jQuery in this.

Comment: No one seems to understand what the OP really is asking for. His last line says `e.g. 07:00pm`. A simple `new Date()` object will not achieve this. He'll need to convert it to a non-24 hour format.

Comment: well he tagged jquery and i couldnt tell if he wanted it specifically in the `title` tag or just simply wanted to know how to inject a variable from javascript into any tag, but you're right....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the local time and save it to a javascript variable:

`var d = new Date();`

Add the date to your desired html tag:

`$("#idOfTag").append(d);`